# Missing operand in for loop

Tags: ada

I have such a bubble sort statement;

```
   procedure Bubble_Sort (Data: in out List) is

      sorted: Boolean := false;
      last : Integer := Data'LAST;
      temp  : Integer;

   begin

      while (not (sorted)) loop
         sorted := true;
         for check in range Data'First..(last-1) loop
            if Data(check) < Data(check+1) then
               -- swap two elements
               temp := Data(check);
               Data(check) := Data(check+1);
               Data(check+1) := temp;
               -- wasn't already sorted after all
               sorted := false;
            end if;
         end loop;
         last := last - 1;
      end loop;

   end Bubble_sort;
```

I have defined 'Data' like this:

```
   Unsorted : constant List := (10, 5, 3, 4, 1, 4, 6, 0, 11, -1);
   Data : List(Unsorted'Range);
```

And the type definition of 'List' is;

```
type List    is array (Index range <>) of Element;
```

on the line

> for check in range Data'Range loop

I get missing operand error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't `check` be declared first?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `check` is declared by the `for` loop -- but only if it's written with the correct syntax.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry, haven't dealt with ADA like a decade for now...

Comment: You changed the code from `for check in range Data'Range` to `for check in range Data'First..(last-1)`. The former should be correct; the latter may or may not be depending on how the type `List` is defined (which you haven't shown us).

Comment: I'm editing question right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `range` keyword:
`for check in Data'Range loop`

The `range` keyword is used to define ranges and subtypes (sometimes anonymous), which is not needed when you use the 'Range attribute.

Comment: Thank you egilhh, but I get the error : 'incompatible types in range' error at this time.

Comment: you define last to be an Integer. I'm guessing List is defined as an array with another subtype as range?

Comment: yes, you are right,    Unsorted : constant List := (10, 5, 3, 4, 1, 4, 6, 0, 11, -1);
   Data : List(Unsorted'Range);

Comment: Now how can I deal with the problem? :)

Comment: You need to show us the type definition of List, not how it's used.

Comment: You mean this?    type List    is array (Index range <>) of Element;

Comment: Yes. Try to define `last` to be of type `Index`, instead of `Integer`

Comment: Thank you egilhh. At this time, I get the error on 'temp : = Data(check)' line. 'temp' should also be Index type, right?